# How to use Javascript to click on an html item (A spreadsheet text box?) that has a different ID each time you click?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a teacher with the worst possible slow gradebook, so much so that I would like to use some code to automate it. Basically to submit a grade I need to:

1. Find the cell box and click on it once to show the submit button
2. Then click on the button

HOWEVER: Every time you click on the box or button it gives it a new html ID. Therefore I need some code that looks for all the boxes and buttons and hits them. I am not sure how to do this without a static ID.

My code is most definitely formatted improperly, I am a total beginner.

```
var selectorBox = ['name_of_cell']
var selectorCollection = ['name_of_button']

selectorBox.forEach((s) =>{
let element = document.querySelector(s);
if(element) element.click();
else console.warn('No element found for the supplied selector:', s);
});

selectorCollection.forEach((s) =>{
let element = document.querySelector(s);
if(element) element.click();
else console.warn('no element found for the supplied selector:', s);
});
```

I need help:

1. Reformatting to the proper syntax / spacing etc.
2. Writing a function that finds and clicks on the box THEN the button (the above works).
3. Making my code look for the boxes then buttons, however as mentioned above the ID for each box and button switches every time you click on one, and for each different class i have (I have about 400 students.)

Comment: Check if there is a class. You could then use a single click event on all items of that class type.

Comment: This is the class: 'x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-headerId-markingperiodcolumn-1202 x-unselectable'

Comment: There is also an inner one: class="x-grid-cell-inner "

Answer (score 0):

If you can select cells/buttons by class, you can loop through all cells, "click" them, and then "click" the button once it appears.

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('.x-grid-cell');
cells.foreach((cell) => {
    cell.click();
    var button = document.querySelector('.class_of_your_button')
    button.click()
})
```